# Indexing in python dataframe using iloc to select all columns except the first column

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, multiple-columns

I am trying to select all columns in a pandas dataframe in python except the first column using iloc.

I am able to select all column except the last one using the code

```
Pre_Processed.iloc[:,0:-1]
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Pre_Processed.iloc[:, 1:] ... google indexing in python.... you index like - iterable[start:end:step]

Comment: It's also called 'slicing'.  Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Pre_Processed.iloc[:,1:]
```

Index with iterable works like

```
iterable[start:end:stride]
```

Read more about stride in

[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3#:~:text=The%20third%20parameter%20specifies%20the,two%20index%20numbers%20is%20retrieved](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3#:%7E:text=The%20third%20parameter%20specifies%20the,two%20index%20numbers%20is%20retrieved).